# Remove option with value = MRW if I checkbox if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove a option with value equal to `MRW` if `#natural_person_lives_in_ccs_0` is checked but if I unchecked the checkbox then the SELECT should be as it was by default meaning same options. This is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lives_in_css = $('#natural_person_lives_in_ccs_0').is(':checked');

  if (lives_in_css) {
      $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").remove();
  } else {
      $(".shipping_from").append('<option value="MRW">Option1</option>');
  }
});
```

But it's not working since `Option1` is added by default and I don't know how to write this. I think to use `.toggle()` but don't know if it's the right one. I leave a [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yOhJYbIsPC9iXFyQ2Gpv) for testing. Any help on this?

Steps:

1. Check `Yes` option value=MRW should be removed
2. Remove the check from `Yes` option value=MRW as by default (same position)

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: @RahulGupta Plunker isn't the same?

Comment: [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYP84/) your code works !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `.change()` function to accomplish your task here,

```
$('#natural_person_lives_in_ccs_0').click(function () {
    var elem = $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']");
    if (this.checked) {
        elem.remove();
    } else if (elem.length == 0) {
        $(".shipping_from").prepend('<option value="MRW">Option1</option>');
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TCAT7/2/)

The best way would be,

```
$('#natural_person_lives_in_ccs_0').click(function () {
    $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").toggle(!this.checked);
    $(".shipping_from option:eq(" + ((this.checked) ? 1 : 0) + ")").prop('selected', true);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TCAT7/1/)

Comment: I'm need to add the ability to enabled/disabled another element `#natural_person` on the same behavior checkbox enabled/disabled, what code do I need to add in order to get this part too? Apologies I forgot to mention on main post

Comment: @ReynierPM Consolidate your code with my answer and ask that problem as a new one. Because, if we solve that problem here through comment, it will be helpful for you not for the other future visitors. :) I Guess you got what i meant. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your script like bellow.

```
var showOptionsAcorrdingCheckbox = function(){
    var lives_in_css = $('#natural_person_lives_in_ccs_0').is(':checked');

    if (lives_in_css) {
        $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").remove();
    } else {
        $(".shipping_from").append('<option value="MRW">Option1</option>');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':checkbox').change(showOptionsAcorrdingCheckbox);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/3mTzT/)**
code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#natural_person_lives_in_ccs_0', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").remove();
        }
        else 
        {
          $(".shipping_from").append('<option value="MRW">Option1</option>');
        }
    });
  });
```